# Allowing users to add their own watermark in PHP

Tags: php, image, file-upload, watermark

Is it fine to allow users to add their own watermark & what filters should i use to upload a correct file. Is watermark only image or text also ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally don't think it's really necessary to let users add their own watermarks to images. But it depends on your requirements. It can be done with PHP using alpha channels.

A very good example from [PHP Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/image.examples-watermark.php):

```
<?php
// Load the stamp and the photo to apply the watermark to
$stamp = imagecreatefrompng('stamp.png');
$im = imagecreatefromjpeg('photo.jpeg');

// Set the margins for the stamp and get the height/width of the stamp image
$marge_right = 10;
$marge_bottom = 10;
$sx = imagesx($stamp);
$sy = imagesy($stamp);

// Copy the stamp image onto our photo using the margin offsets and the photo 
// width to calculate positioning of the stamp. 
imagecopy($im, $stamp, imagesx($im) - $sx - $marge_right, imagesy($im) - $sy - $marge_bottom, 0, 0, imagesx($stamp), imagesy($stamp));

// Output and free memory
header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

**Sample Output:**

[image]

Hope this helps!